# How can I join the same data for different columns?

Tags: sql

I am sstruggling to make a query to join the corresponding replacing the IDs.
I have two tables USERS and CONNECTIONS.

Users:

```
user_id  first_name
--------------------
     3   Jim
     4   Pam
     5   Michael
```

Connections:

```
user_id  friend_id
--------------------
     3   4
     4   3
     4   5
     5   4
```

In Connections both columns includes the user_id from Users to represent the connection between the people.
I need the result like below:

```
user     friend
----------------
Jim       Pam
Pam       Jim
Pam       Michael
Michael   Pam
```

Comment: What have you tried so far???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Joining `Connections` table with `Users` tables give the expected result.

By using `U1.user_id = C.user_id` to get the `user` and using `U2.user_id = C.friend_id` to get the `friend` values.

```
SELECT U1.first_name AS user, U2.first_name AS friend
FROM Connections C
JOIN Users U1 ON U1.user_id = C.user_id
JOIN Users U2 ON U2.user_id = C.friend_id
```

[**Demo on db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a8653ca41bbfe0d02a18f567c7ab9c3b)

**output:**

```
user        friend
--------------------
Jim         Pam
Pam         Jim
Pam         Michael
Michael     Pam
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I was trying to do with two joins but I missed something.

Answer (score 0):

[This is for SQL Server.  Was not aware that the OP was using postgres.]

This should do the trick.  Just need to join the users table twice (once for the user, and again for the friend)

```
SELECT
     [User].[first_name] AS [UserName]
    ,[Friend].[first_name] AS [FriendName]
FROM [User]
    INNER JOIN [Connections] ON [Connections].[user_id] = [User].[user_id]
    INNER JOIN [User] AS [Friend] ON [Friend].[user_id] = [Connections].[friend_id]
```

Comment: I am using postgres, it did not executes, might be an issue with the brackets, I am not sure but thanks for the help anyway.